# Sending POST data without form

Tags: php, post, data-transfer

Can i send for example a string or another piece of information to another .php file without it being exposed [thus not by GET but by POST conform to what i know] without using a form?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use sessions.

Comment: It's not entirely clear where you are sending the data from and to. Is it Client to Server or Server to Server or Server to different Server?

Comment: well i pass it along from one file to another on the same server

Comment: The data will be almost equally well-exposed through POST as it is through GET, the key value pairs will just not show up in the address bar but the information is still being transferred in the clear unless you are using SSL or this is strictly a server-to-server type of thing over a secured communication channel.

Comment: POST data is extremely visible to the user (just not your typical user). Sessions are the way to go.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you don't want your data to be seen by the user, use a PHP session.

Data in a post request is still accessible (and manipulable) by the user.

Checkout [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) on PHP Sessions.

Comment: this not a good soloution, also if the author accepted this as a workaround. also sessions are way easier to hijack than manupilating a post request (ie. by  a "man in the middle" attack)

Comment: Why is this a bad solution? Perhaps Samuel's process is such that hijacking the session is not an issue. The only way to truly solve session hijacking (in a unobtrusive way) is using SSL for all session related requests. If Samuel was worried about the data being leaked, he should use SSL.

Comment: @zolex, what is so difficult about intercepting post data? Sitting in a coffee shop with WireShark running is all you need to hijack POST data. Recreate the request with cookies and post data, and you are good to go. If you consider sessions to be a bad solution, then SSL is the only good solution.

Comment: classical user-fail when sending sensitive data from a coffee shop ;) and btw, the question was how to send post data with php, to not expose the data in the url so ie. it wont get logged by the webserver etc. i think this was the main purpose... my answer really answers teh question and does not provide some overhead workaround like yours. well if he's fine with that. KISS ;)

Answer (score 23):

You could use AJAX to send a POST request if you don't want forms.

Using jquery [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method it is pretty simple:

```
$.post('/foo.php', { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }, function(result) {
    alert('successfully posted key1=value1&key2=value2 to foo.php');
});
```

Comment: That is javascript.  AJAX = Asynchronous Javascript And XML

Comment: @Samuel, now if you say that no javascript is allowed then things become rather impossible :-)

Comment: I didn't know AJAX was Javascript and I can't really use Javascript

Comment: What can you use in fact? Are you developing a web site or something else because saying that you cannot use forms and javascript seems like you start with a great handicap in web development from the beginning? Is it because technically you don't know javascript or there's some other reason?

Comment: i can't use javascript for core functions and i was looking for ways to pass along information without forms, i could maybe use hidden forms but i was looking for a more elegant way (i completely forgot about sessions)

Comment: this is probably the best answer here, using jquery to do the heavy lifting, and this also works after the page has been rendered.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Can we send json array with post request.
I want to send array with post request.

Comment: The question tags is PHP, this is not PHP

Comment: How to post the output data to another PHP page using the POST method, https://www.pastiebin.com/5d1da8d6643ec and my retrieve PHP code is : https://www.pastiebin.com/5d1da94043f95 @Darin Dimitrov

Answer (score 12):

Send your data with SESSION rather than post.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = "bar";
```

On the page where you recieve the request, if you absolutely need POST data (some weird logic), you can do this somwhere at the beginning:

```
$_POST['foo'] = $_SESSION['foo'];
```

The post data will be valid just the same as if it was sent with POST.

Then destroy the session (or just unset the fields if you need the session for other purposes).

It is important to destroy a session or unset the fields, because unlike POST, SESSION will remain valid until you explicitely destroy it or until the end of browser session. If you don't do it, you can observe some strange results. For example: you use sesson for filtering some data. The user switches the filter on and gets filtered data. After a while, he returns to the page and expects the filter to be reset, but it's not: he still sees filtered data.

Comment: session does work withing the defined domain URL, but this may not be ideal solutions when you need to move data cross urls

Answer (score 10):

Simply use: `file_get_contents()`

```
// building array of variables
$content = http_build_query(array(
            'username' => 'value',
            'password' => 'value'
            ));
// creating the context change POST to GET if that is relevant 
$context = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => $content, )));

$result = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/page.php', null, $context);
//dumping the reuslt
var_dump($result);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46981656/7735285): my answer to a similar question:

Answer (score 5):

have a look at the php documentation for theese functions you can send post reqeust using them.

```
fsockopen()
fputs()
```

or simply use a class like **Zend_Http_Client** which is also based on socket-conenctions.

also found a [neat example](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/post-request.htm) using google...

Answer (score 2):

```js
function redir(data) {
  document.getElementById('redirect').innerHTML = '<form style="display:none;" position="absolute" method="post" action="location.php"><input id="redirbtn" type="submit" name="value" value=' + data + '></form>';
  document.getElementById('redirbtn').click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="redir('dataToBeSent');">Next Page</button>
<div id="redirect"></div>
```

You can use this method which creates a new hidden form whose "data" is sent by "post" to "location.php" when a button[Next Page] is clicked.

Comment: OP asked for a solution without using a form. This answer uses a form?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using curl in such situation, `file_get_content()` does work but not at all times, and it could be troublesome to use it in some applications.

Though curl comes in different variations depending on what you want to send and in what method, here is the most common method of posting your data without HTML form using curl.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/request_uri');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $post = array(
        'data1' => 'value1',
        'data2' => $value2
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    
    //do what you want with the responce
    var_dump($result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution, you can insert a form in your html code and just hide the input

```
<!-- HTML code -->
    
<?php

$passedDate = 'your date';


echo '

<form action="secondPage.php" method="post">
      <input style="display:none" type="text" name="data" value="' . $passedData . '">
      
  <button type="submit" value="submit">
  
  
  </form>'
?>

<!-- HTML code -->
```

then you can easly get that passed date in the second page without need input from the user

```
<?php

echo $_POST['data'];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).