# Send a $_POST request to another page without a form

Tags: php, post, request

I'm currently busy with PHP and thought of sending a `POST` request to another page without a form to do so. But how do you do this? I googled a bit and saw that cURL was used: is this the best way to go or can you do it (easy) without it?

I was thinking of making a small page where suggestions can be placed and you could decline / accept them. The suggestions are loaded from a (MySQL) database and presented along with an accept and decline button. If accept is clicked i would like to send the parameters to a page that accepts `POST` as in this way:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'] && isset($_POST['text'])) 
{
    // ...
}
```

I do know this can be done with `$_GET`, but i'd like to do it by `$_POST` for a change.

Comment: Examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757569/sending-data-using-post-method-without-form/6757695#6757695

Comment: if it's really that important, use a session. AJAX still relies on the client side to support JS, and some people are still paranoid an turn it off all together. Sessions are your best bet, IMO

Comment: Please, in the interest of helping other people looking for the same thing, choose one answer and mark it as accepted. Lets make a better and a more valuable resource for the community! :)

Comment: Internet had some trouble with me, so couldn't vote. Anyway it's up now so i've voted. @kyokasuigetsu I am loading multiple suggestions from a db with 2 buttons. The suggestions are entered somewhere else so all i have to do is click accept / decline. If i accept i would like to send it to another page which i've already created a while ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery to do a post request. More information can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

An example would be:

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

If you have difficulty implementing, feel free to ask further.

Comment: Hmmm this looks interesting. I've never used ajax before so this'll do! Something new to learn is always welcome

Comment: Good luck! Ajax is great for some things, but don't overdo it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can send Posts easily via Javascript (Ajax), see jQuery Ajax for examples. Or in PHP just use CURL, it is very easy to use.

If you need a curl-free alternative, use fopen like
http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/

see also http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

There are two acceptable methods:

1. **Sessions** - Instead of using `$_POST`, use `$_SESSION`

   *Reference*: [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)
2. **AJAX** - You can send POST requests without a form.

   *Reference*: [AJAX tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) / [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)